# How to Debootstrap specific version in Ubuntu or Debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, filesystems, debootstrap

i want to install a specific version of Ubuntu or Debian, In ubuntu i want to debootstrap the specific version 16.04.0, and i'm using this code:

```
debootstrap --arch=amd64 --variant=buildd xenial "/home/ubuntu/Documents/myrootfilesystemdir" http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

But unfortunately, after finish the debootstrap second stage, the version installed is 16.04.6.

Now in debian, the same situation, i need to install debian stretch 9.0.0, using this code:

```
debootstrap --arch amd64 --foreign stretch "/home/ubuntu/Documents/myrootfilesystemdir" http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian
```

And the version after the second stage of bootstrap is 9.9.0.

Exist any way to debootstrap specific version for example:

```
debootstrap --arch amd64 --foreign stretch --version 9.0.0
```

Or another alternative to bootstrap to install a specific version when i build a root filesystem?

Or Which configuration file of bootstrap i have to edit to specify the version that i want to install?

Or another alternative to debootstrap package, for build a root filesystems?

Note: I need to work in the initial version releases ej: 9.0.0 in debian and 16.04.0 in ubuntu, to not leave the support for the initial versions, for example if i work in a last release(ubuntu 16.04.6) the support will be incompatible with a the previus versions until the initial version 16.04.0, thats why i need keep a range 16.04.0+ (16.04.0 to 16.04.6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian doesn’t maintain old point releases in an installable form in its main archives, and I don’t think Ubuntu does either; a new network-based install of either will install the current point release.

However, at least for Debian, you can use snapshots to install an older point release. See [this Super User Q&A](https://superuser.com/q/1312623/414739) for details: you can extract the appropriate timestamp from the Jigdo files of whatever point-release you’re after, and use the result as the archive for `debootstrap`:

```
$ wget -q -O - https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/9.0.0/amd64/jigdo-bd/debian-9.0.0-amd64-BD-1.jigdo | gunzip | awk -F= '/snapshot.debian.org/ {print $2}'
http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20170617T130639Z/
```

Comment: Thank you, of course Ubuntu or Debian makes a install in the last version of a release, now i will read more about that you say before.

Comment: One question more, the use for the snapshot is like this command `debootstrap --arch amd64 /home/ubuntu/Documents/myrootfilesystemdir http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20170617T130639Z/`?

Comment: Or, i have to keep the argument `--foreign stretch`?