# Debian 10 : Upgrade to specific minor release (10.10)

Tags: debian

I need to upgrade Debian to a specific minor release : from 10.9 to 10.10 (to be iso with another environment).
The problem is if I run `apt-get update` then `apt-get dist-update` : the release is 10.11...

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Debian doesn’t keep old point-releases in its main archives; see [Why do previous versions of Debian packages vanish in the package repositories? (highly relevant for version-controlled system configuration)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/544432/86440) for more details on that.

There is however a workaround: it is possible to determine the timestamp for a given release, and use that with [snapshot.debian.org](https://snapshot.debian.org/) (see [How to Debootstrap specific version in Ubuntu or Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/533849/86440)). In your case:

```sh
$ wget -q -O - https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/10.10.0/amd64/jigdo-bd/debian-10.10.0-amd64-BD-1.jigdo | gunzip | awk -F= '/snapshot.debian.org/ {print $2}'
http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20210620T161105Z/ --try-last
```

Use that timestamp in an entry such as

```
deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20210620T161105Z/ buster main
```

and (temporarily) *disable* the main Debian 10 entries — running `apt update && apt upgrade` will then upgrade you to the package versions as they were when Debian 10.10 was released.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that *this is not necessary* in most cases – debian is a distro both very concerned and experienced with package management and not making breaking changes. In other words, any software that could be compiled the day Debian 10 is released should still compile on a fully updated debian 10 the day debian 10 goes end-of-life.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I went into some detail regarding that aspect in the linked answer.