# Debian: How to mirror a minor version that is not the current one

Tags: debian, apt, apt-mirror

I use Debians apt-mirror to create a local mirror.

Here's the entry in /etc/apt/mirror.list for getting lastest Debian 11 - that is 11.7.

```
deb http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian bullseye main
```

What to do when I need a specific minor version (e.g. 11.1) of bookworm?
How can I get this with apt-mirror or otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the relevant timestamp and point your mirror to the appropriate snapshot; see [Debian 10 : Upgrade to specific minor release (10.10)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/688971/86440) and the links there for details.

You may need to disable key verification; see [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org/).

(In most cases you shouldn’t need older point releases but I imagine you have your reasons!)